# If $|G| \nmid m!$, then $\exists \ H \neq \{e\} $ that $H \leq K$ and $H \unlhd G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a Group and $K \leq G$ such as $[G:K]=m$.

Show that if $|G| \nmid m!$, then $\exists \ H \neq \{e\} $ that $H \leq K$ and $H \unlhd G$.

Any leads?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let set $U=\{xK, x\in G\}$,
for each element $g \in G$, define $\sigma_g: U\to U$ so that $\sigma_g(xK)=(gx)K$.
and $\sigma_{g_1}\sigma_{g_2}=\sigma_{g_1g_2}$
It is easy to show that $\{\sigma_g, g\in G\}$ forms a group $S$ which is a subgroup of $S_m$.

The mapping $\varphi: G\to S$ with $\varphi(g)=\sigma_g$ is a group homomorphim so that
$|G|=|\ker(\varphi)||S|$.

Since $|G| \nmid m!$, it means $|\ker(\varphi)| \gt 1$ so that $\ker(\varphi) \unlhd G$

Comment: Why $|G| ∤ m! \Rightarrow |ker(φ)| > 1$? Is the only thing I didn't get.

Comment: because S is subgroup of $S_m$ and $|S_m|=m!$. If $|ker(\varphi)|=1$, we will have $|G|=|S| \mid m!$